# Using text editor for configuring Jenkins job's UI elements

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to edit/save the code of "Job Configuration" (the structure and order of UI elements) ?

The pipeline job get the pipeline code from git, but this occurs only AFTER the job started. I want to edit the UI of job parameters (BEFORE user press "build")

Its necessary for 2 reasons :

1. its much easier to cut/paste text lines, than move elements up/down with the mouse.
2. can be saved and deployed easily on a new Jenkins machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the configuration before the job is run to add the initial build parameters. If you then have the build parameters also defined in the pipeline, the parameters will be overwritten with the ones defined in the pipeline.

However, for that first build, if the build parameters defined in the job configuration and the ones in the pipeline match, the build parameter values will be used in that initial run.

Comment: How that answers my question ? its not about who is overriding the values... i want to edit the UI elements (change variable orders, move seperators up/down etc.) this is painful to do in the UI ...

Comment: You can define build parameters in your Jenkinsfile. Checkout this example: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters-example

One limitation you should be aware of is that the UI will not update the build parameters until the first execution of the job. So the first build may have no build parameters, but when you try to run it again, you will be presented with all the build parameters you defined in your Jenkinsfile / pipeline definition.